# CCA Security/Decryption of PRF scheme

Tags: chosen-ciphertext-attack, decryption

Let $F : \{0,1\}^n \times \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n $ be a PRF. And let the encryption function be $Enc{_k}(m) = r\mathbin\| (F{_k}(m\bigoplus r)$ , r being a random value.

Im trying to proof that this scheme is not CCA-secure, however I'm already failing at finding a correct decryption. Since a PRF is not invertible, how is it possible to recover the $m$ from the ciphertext?

Comment: What you have there can in general not be decrypted. Where did you find this supposed scheme? Are you sure it's not supposed to be $(r,F_k(r) \oplus m)$?

Comment: Hint: Do you understand why CBC mode is not CCA secure? Notice that this scheme is CBC mode restricted to a single plaintext block (assuming F is a PRP).